# How can I draw a table where the upper left corner is missing? (Pic)

Tags: tables, formatting

Is it possible to draw a table like the one in the attached picture? I've read documentation on the `tabular` environment but nothing really describes this well.
The shading would be nice but the crucial part is the layout (5 columns, 2x2 merged cells on the top row and the top left 2 cells have no shading or border)

[image]

Comment: [Here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Spanning_in_both_directions_simultaneously) it is a good explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`colortbl` can add the grey:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{colortbl,hhline}

\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
\definecolor{g}{rgb}{.8,.8,.8}
\begin{document}

$
\begin{array}{|*5{c|}}
\hhline{~----}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{g}c}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{g}\lnot c }\\
\hhline{~----}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\cellcolor{g}b&\cellcolor{g}\lnot b&\cellcolor{g}b&\cellcolor{g}\lnot b\\
\hline
\cellcolor{g}a&&0.33&0.03&\\
\hline
\cellcolor{g}\lnot a&&0.17&0.01&\\
\hline
\end{array}
$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

This can be done using the `\multicolumn` which has syntax

```
\multicolumn{<number of cells to span>}{<justification>}{<content>}
```

and the `\cline` command which takes arguments

```
 \cline{<start column>-<end column>}
```

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \cline{2-5}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{}  &   \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{c} &   \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{c}\\
  \cline{2-5}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{}  &   \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{b}   &   b   &   b   &   b\\\hline
   a &      &   $.33$   &   $0.03$   &   \\\hline
   a &      &   $.33$   &   $0.03$   &   \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The following solution uses `\multicolumn` and `\cline` to get the empty cells without lines.
It solves the problem of `colortbl` that the cell background color overprints the lines by setting the table twice, the first time with background color, the second time without.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{tabgray}{gray}{.8}

\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\MyTable}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}{|>{#1}c|c|c|c|c|}
    \cline{2-5}
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &
    \multicolumn{2}{>{#1}c|}{c} &
    \multicolumn{2}{>{#1}c|}{$\lnot$c} \\
    \cline{2-5}
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &
    % b & $\lnot$b & b & $\lnot$b \\
    \multicolumn{1}{>{#1}c|}{b} &
    \multicolumn{1}{>{#1}c|}{$\lnot$b} &
    \multicolumn{1}{>{#1}c|}{b} &
    \multicolumn{1}{>{#1}c|}{$\lnot$b} \\
    \hline
    a & & 0.33 & 0.03 & \\
    \hline
    $\lnot$a & & 0.17 & 0.01 & \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}%
}%
\leavevmode
\rlap{\MyTable{\columncolor{tabgray}}}%
\mbox{\MyTable{}}%
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]